# CD Library ripped in Windows - Import to iTunes with track/album info?

Tags: itunes

I have a library of CDs, originally ripped in Windows Media Player, that contains album, artist and track info.

I want to import this library into iTunes in Windows (version 12.9.5.7, current).

The audio was ripped in ALAC format and imports just fine into iTunes.  However, iTunes does not bring over any album/artist/track info.  There does not seem to be an option in iTunes to fetch this information after the fact.

***Question:*** How do I get iTunes to fetch album/artist/track info for audio originally imported in WMP?

Comment: Can we assume you're talking about iTunes in Windows? Also, what version of iTunes are you using?

Comment: I added the information to the question.